# Javascript class instance problem

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to figure out JavaScript OOP, I tried the following which works but fails when I need to make a change to a class variable on a specific instance.

I have "myname" with a default value, I then change it for a specific instance and in an event handler I print it's value. I get the default value and not the updated one.

how can I change the code to support this ?

thanks

```
function myClass () {}

myClass.prototype = 
{

    myname : "test",

    test  : function (filename)
    {
        var img = createSomething ();
        img.container = this;

        img.addEventListener('click', this.onClick);                    
    }, 


    onClick : function (e)
    {
        trace ("click: " + e.source.container.myname); // this will print "test" and not "dave"
    }

};



var instance = new myClass ();

instance.myname = "dave";

instance.test();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do OOP, you must use a bind function. It is extremely useful when you want to attach event handlers that are bound to your object rather than the global object.

```
function bind(func, context) {
     return function() {
          return func.apply(context, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
     }
}
```

Then you do this-

```
function MyClass() {}

MyClass.prototype = {

    myname: "test",

    test: function(filename) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/f00/fff.png&text=my+image"

        img.addEventListener('click', bind(this.onClick, this), false);
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    },
    onClick: function(e) {
        //this here refers to the instance of MyClass
        console.log("click: " + this.myname); 
    }
};
var instance = new MyClass();
instance.myname = "dave";
instance.test();
```

PS: As a convention, constructor functions (or 'Classes') begin with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `trace()` and `e.source` are, but when I take your example, and use `console.log()` and `e.target.container.myname`, it works perfectly.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/L2UMC/2/

*(note that the example is only intended to work in browsers that support addEventListener)*

```
function myClass() {}

myClass.prototype = {

    myname: "test",

    test: function(filename) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/f00/fff.png&text=my+image"
        img.container = this;

        img.addEventListener('click', this.onClick, false);
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    },
    onClick: function(e) {
        console.log("click: " + e.target.container.myname); 
    }
};
var instance = new myClass();
instance.myname = "dave";
instance.test();
```

---

**EDIT:** Made the `addEventListener` more compatible by adding the 3rd argument, as correctly suggested by [@Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling).

Comment: I guess you more less copied&pasted the original code, but note that at least Firefox needs three arguments for `addEventListener`: `img.addEventListener('click', this.onClick, false);`(it will throw an error otherwise). This makes it at least a bit more compatible ;)

Comment: @Felix: Thanks for the info. I only tested in Chrome. I'll update. Main point was that the inheritance was working properly. This is most certainly limited in terms of browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: not a direct answer to the question.*

For OOP in Javascript I would strongly recommend using following Class class by John Resig himself: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

It makes inheritance so much nicer...